# how to compute the original vector from a distance matrix?

Tags: vector, matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, euclidean-distance

I have a small question about vector and matrix.

Suppose a vector V = {v1, v2, ..., vn}. I generate a n-by-n distance matrix M defined as:

M_ij = | v_i - v_j |  such that i,j belong to [1, n].

That is, each element M_ij in the square matrix is the absolute distance of two elements in V.

For example, I have a vector V = {1, 3, 3, 5}, the distance matrix will be
M=[
0  2  2  4;
2  0  0  2;
2  0  0  2;
4  2  2  0; ]

It seems pretty simple. Now comes to the question. Given such a matrix M, how to obtain the initial V?

Thank you.

Based on some answer for this question, it seems that the answer is not unique. So, now suppose that all the initial vector has been normalized to 0 mean and 1 variance. The question is: Given such a symmetric distance matrix M, how to decide the initial normalized vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. To give you an idea of why, consider these two cases:

> V1 = {1,2,3}
>
> M1 = [ 0 1 2 ; 1 0 1 ; 2 1 0 ]
>
> V2 = {3,4,5}
>
> M2 = [ 0 1 2 ; 1 0 1 ; 2 1 0 ]

As you can see, a single M could be the result of more than one V. Therefore, you can't map backwards.

Comment: Maybe it is better to let any of the initial vector is normalized to 0 mean and 1 variance. I will add this requirement to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine the answer uniquely, since the distance matrix is invariant to adding a constant to all elements and to multiplying all the values by -1.  Assuming that element 1 is equal to 0, and that the first nonzero element is positive, however, you can find an answer.  Here is the pseudocode:

```
# Assume v[1] is 0
v[1] = 0
# e is value of first non-zero vector element
e = 0
# ei is index of first non-zero vector element
ei = 0
for i = 2...n:
  # if all vector elements have been 0 so far
  if e == 0:
    # get the current distance from element 1 and its index
    # this new element may still be 0
    e = d[1,i]
    ei = i
    v[i] = e
  elseif d[1,i] == d[ei,i] + v[ei]: # v[i] <= v[1]
    # v[i] is to the left of v[1] (assuming v[ei] > v[1])
    v[i] = -d[1,i]
  else:
    # some other case; v[i] is to the right of v[1]
    v[i] = d[1,i]
```

Comment: What if any of the initial vector is normalized to 0 mean and 1 variance? Is it possible for you to add some comment to your code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @sunjerry: What do you mean by "mean" and "variance" here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to find the original vector, but you can find a translation of the vector by taking the first row of the matrix.

If you let M_ij = | v_i - v_j | and you translate all v_k for k\in [1,n] you will get
M_ij = | v-i + 1 - v_j + 1 | 
     = | v_i - v_j |

Hence, just take the first row as the vector and find one initial point to translate the vector to.

Correction:

```
Let v_1 = 0, and let l_k = | v_k | for k\in [2,n] and p_k the parity of v_k

Let p_1 = 1

for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
   if( | l_i - l_(i+1) | != M_i(i+1) )
      p_(i+1) = - p_i
   else
      p_(i+1) = p_i
```

doing this for all v_k for k\in [2,n] in order will show the parity of each v_k in respect to the others

Then you can find a translation of the original vector with the same or opposite direction

Update (For Normalized vector):

```
  Let d = Sqrt(v_1^2 + v_2^2 + ... + v_n^2)

  Vector = {0, v_1 / d, v_2 / d, ... , v_n / d}
            or
           {0, -v_1 / d, -v_2 / d, ... , -v_n / d}
```

Comment: That breaks because some of the vector values could be negative (when v[1] is normalized to 0), and that would not appear in the first row of the matrix.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I suppose the best you can do is finding which v_k have same parity. For example, you know from the first row +/- v_k for all k > 1 (letting v_1 = 0), then from |v_a - v_b| = M_ab you can find whether they have similar parity or not (this would lead to 2 vectors opposite to each other)

Comment: Thank you @Yuuta for your answer. That is pretty illuminating. But I do not get your point in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, I put the comment before I updated my answer. You can get the transpose of the vector but the original point and the direction is not known. For example, you can find {0,v_2,v_3...} but the original vector is s*{0 + t,v_2 + t,v_3 + t,...} for some t where s is +/- 1